# Pipeline with nightly deploy, deploys twice

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want my pipeline to continuously build and run unit test during the day and automatically deploy the latest build at midnight. Also need to be able to manually force deploy if needed. My problem is that the first build of the day is not cancelled, so the pipeline will deploy twice.

Maybe if I create a separate job that locks the deploy resource just before midnight and releases it some time after just to make sure that all builds are in queue for lock so that 'inversePrecedence' prunes all older builds. Is there a simpler solution?

```
stage('build')
node('myNode') {
    sh 'build.ksh'
    sh 'runtest.ksh'
    stash includes: 'Builds/', name: 'Builds'
}

// Wait for midnight to deploy
milestone 1
stage('wait for midnight')
if (!isMidnight()) {
    waitForMidnightOrManualTrigger()
}

milestone 2
stage('deploy')
lock(resource: 'deploy-server', inversePrecedence: true) {
    node('myNode') {
        unstash 'Builds'
        sh "deploy.ksh"
    }
}

milestone 3


def isMidnight() {
    int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    return hour < 1
}

def waitForMidnightOrManualTrigger() {
    echo 'Wait until midnight. Or Force deploy. Or abort.'
    try {
        waitTime = getMillisToMidnight()
        timeout(time: waitTime, unit: 'MILLISECONDS') {
            input 'Click Proceed to force deploy now. Or wait till midnight for automatic deploy.'
        }
    } catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e){
        if (isAborted(e)) {
            echo "The job was aborted by user"
            throw e
        } else {
            echo "Timeout reached, proceed!"
        }
    }
}

def getMillisToMidnight() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
}

// There might be an easier way to differ between if the timeout throws the
// exception or if it is the user that has aborted the build...
def isAborted(e) {
        def stackTrace = e.getStackTrace()
        for (int i=0; i<stackTrace.size(); ++i) {
            if (stackTrace[i].toString().contains("InputStepExecution.stop")) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a separate job for deployment and use a simple CRON to trigger this deploy job twice a day ? You seem to have a very complicated pipeline that clearly treats two different concerns, I'd say that you don't need to do everything with a single pipeline here, just move your deploy script to another pipeline !

Comment: What if the latest code does not pass test? With a separate deploy job nothing would be deployed?

Comment: I don't think separate jobs add a problem : you can always check if you actually have a built artifact (from job 1) in your second job and deploy it only if it exists !